# Showing back div on click after div fade out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form where user click button to update profile. After `<div>` give them notice it will fade out. It works but the problem is when user click submit button again the `<div>` will not show again. My code in :

```
function(data){

    if (data.response==1) 
    { 
        $('#stage').html("<div style=\"background-color:#75A838; padding-left:20px;\">Your profile has been updated!</div>"); 
    }
    else if (data.response==0) {
    $('#stage').html("<div style=\"background-color:#FF7800; padding-left:20px;\">No changes have been made to your profile!</div>");
   }
            $('#stage').delay(2000).fadeOut();
```

html code

```
 <div id="stage" style="color: white;"></div>
```

What did I miss? Help me with this please. Thank you.

Comment: On a side note it would be better to not use inline styles. Instead use addClass() and removeClass()

Comment: @luk2302 - presumably this function is fired when a button outside this code is clicked.

Comment: @luk2302 - you are correct. I can only fade it once and on second submit the div failed to display.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once `fadeOut()` completes it will set the `div` to `display:none;` Here's updated code:

```
function(data){

    if (data.response==1) { 
        $('#stage').show().html("<div style=\"background-color:#75A838; padding-left:20px;\">Your profile has been updated!</div>"); 
    } else if (data.response==0) {
        $('#stage').show().html("<div style=\"background-color:#FF7800; padding-left:20px;\">No changes have been made to your profile!</div>");
    }

    $('#stage').delay(2000).fadeOut();

}
```

The `.show()` on your `div` will make sure the `display:none;` is removed from the `div`.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. That solved it. I shall read up show() function once I got time insya-Allah.

Comment: Thanks @Joe it just helped me to solved my piece of code $('#stage').html(message).show().delay(5000).fadeOut(400).

Answer (score 0):

here's a few links that might be of interest :

[jquery fadein fadeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_fade.asp)

[another of interest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287308/jquery-fade-out-then-fade-in)

[some more of interest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930502/jquery-fadein-fadeout-with-click)